# How to remove all HTML tag exclude some tags

Tags: php, html, tags, removeall

I create a form and I want to use PHP to remove **all HTML tags** but **exclude some tags `(<b>, <strong>, <em>, <i>, <p>, <br>, <ul>, <li> <ol>`... (and some tags for format paragraph)** when members click Submit befor it will be insert into Database.

```
$content = $_POST['content'];
```

Thanks all for help.
I'm sorry if my english isn't good.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$content=strip_tags($content,"<b><strong><em><i><p><br><ul><li><ol>");
```

Comment: Yes that works. However, `strip_tags()` won't have a look at the HTML attributes. So a malicious user could use this for cross site scripting (XSS) and maybe other attacks.

Comment: Very true! I'm also aware that strip_tags will only strip valid tags, and nests might mess it up as well. (Ex. <strong>hello</em>)

Answer (score 3):

The following should do it:

```
// tags separated by vertical bar
$strip_tags = "a|strong|em";

// target html
$html = '<em><a><b>ha<a href="" title="">d</a>f</em></b>';

// Regex is loose and works for closing/opening tags across multiple lines and
// is case-insensitive
// note: The *? makes the matching non-greedy
$clean_html = preg_replace("#<\s*\/?(".$strip_tags.")\s*[^>]*?>#im", '', $html);

// prints "<b>hadf</b>";
echo $html;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `strip_tags()` might be dangerous as it won't have a look at the HTML attributes. So a malicious user could use this for cross site scripting (XSS) and maybe other attacks (as also noted in my comment to David Chen).

Instead I would suggest using an existing HTML filterer as for example http://htmlpurifier.org/ which probably is much more secure and suitable for this task.